# Do not fetch deletion changes using CkFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I use it to fetch all records from cloudkit database. I pass nil token to indicate that I need ALL changes. Later I fetch latest changes with apropriate token.

But first time I get thousends of changes related to deletion. It takes some time... Is there a way to indicate whether I need deletion changes or not? Or can I somehow that type of change mark as received or read and to not get it anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> first time I get thousends of changes related to deletion.

I understand you are mentioning the scenario when you are passing nil value to the server change token in CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOptions.

> Is there a way to indicate whether I need deletion changes or not? Or can I somehow that type of change mark as received or read and to not get it anymore?

You get the IDs of the deleted records in the block: "setRecordWithIDWasDeletedBlock"

> @property (nonatomic, copy, nullable) void (^recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock)(CKRecordID *recordID, NSString *recordType);

Please try by not setting that block property in your operation instance. If the block is NOT set, you won't receive information of the deleted records. So, do not set the block property for the first time (that is, when the change token is nil).

> Later I fetch latest changes with apropriate token.

You can set the above mentioned block only if the change token is non-nil!